# Short Series (Fox Kids Maybe) about a superhero with a magic (or cursed) wheelchair

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember an old animated tv series (I remember animation by flash software), I saw it on fox Kids, early 2000s, urban environment, not futuristic, about a guy (caucasian, mid 30s) who suffers some kind of accident and gets paralyzed, then he receives a wheelchair that turns into a golden armor; remember also that it was like Spawn maybe? like, an armor given by an evil character... that's the only thing I can remember but I loved that series. Don't recall having love interests, just saw a few short chapters. They were like 10/15min. each, I've been looking for it for months.

Comment: I'm willing to be you can give us more than that. Have a look at the checklists here for ideas; https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question

Comment: How old was the show (approximately)? Was this "guy" an adult or a teen? What was his name? Was he Caucasian? Did he have any friends/sidekicks? Why did he need armour? Who gave him the magic wheelchair? In what way was it magical? Was there a love-interest? Was there a villain? What was the setting (e.g. Urban fantasy, modern, etc)? How did he trigger the wheelchair?

Comment: [M.A.N.T.I.S](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YNIbUHXmgjg) has a wheelchair-bound hero, but the chair doesn't turn into armour.